# How do I get the absolute media file path in umbraco using razor?

Tags: razor, umbraco

I've tried the following bit of razor code:

```
@room.Media("summaryImage","umbracoFile")
```

but I get something like `~/media/155/lux.jpg`, how do I remove the initial `~` to get a server path ie, `/media/155/lux.jpg` or `http://some_url/media/155/lux.jpg`?

EDIT:

I've tried

```
@{
  dynamic summaryImagePath = room.Media("summaryImage","umbracoFile");
}
@Page.ResolveUrl(@summaryImagePath)
```

and

```
@Page.ResolveUrl(@room.Media("summaryImage","umbracoFile"))
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Error loading Razor Script Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

even though `@room.Media("summaryImage","umbracoFile")` gives `~/media/155/lux.jpg`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there is a solution within Umbraco, I'd just use the .NET framework. With ASP.NET, you can use [MapPath](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath) to resolve virtual paths to physical file paths:

```
@HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(room.Media("summaryImage","umbracoFile"))
```

EDIT:

If you are looking for the absolute URL, you may use one of the following variants:

```
@Page.ResolveUrl(room.Media("summaryImage","umbracoFile"))
```

or

```
@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(room.Media("summaryImage","umbracoFile"))
```

You may would like to read this [article about different approaches for resolving URLs](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html).

Comment: Using this I get something like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[path to media]\media\155\lux.jpg. I just want the /media/155/lux.jpg bit. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Page.ResolveUrl gave me a null reference error, but VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute worked like a charm!

Comment: Maybe it's because razor scripts don't have a Page context as per: http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html